# From set to set of set?

Tags: python

I have set of elements, I want to convert this set to a list of list of 5 elements.

i.e.

I want set below

```
symbol_list = set([u'DIVISLAB', u'TITAN', u'JINDALSTEL', u'ENDURANCE', u'PGHH', u'GMRINFRA', u'UNIONBANK', u'RAMCOCEM', u'GAIL', u'ICICIGI', u'L&TFH', u'HINDUNILVR', u'SBIN', u'PRESTIGE', u'BERGEPAINT', u'LT', u'HINDPETRO', u'RELIANCE', u'GODREJCP', u'GRAPHITE', u'RELINFRA', u'NBCC', u'MCDOWELL-N', u'SYNGENE', u'IOC', u'PETRONET', u'SUNPHARMA', u'GRASIM', u'FEDERALBNK', u'GRUH', u'CANBK', u'BBTC', u'FCONSUMER', u'MFSL', u'MRF', u'TATACHEM', u'IDFCFIRSTB', u'FRETAIL', u'OIL', u'DBL', u'PFIZER', u'BANKINDIA', u'CHOLAFIN', u'MARUTI', u'HDFC', u'EXIDEIND', u'VOLTAS', u'PAGEIND', u'RELCAPITAL', u'HDFCAMC', u'INDHOTEL', u'INDIGO', u'BHARATFORG', u'BPCL', u'MOTHERSUMI', u'COLPAL', u'LTTS', u'BAJAJHLDNG', u'GICRE', u'KOTAKBANK', u'ABCAPITAL', u'CADILAHC', u'PIDILITIND', u'APOLLOTYRE', u'AUBANK', u'TCS', u'NATCOPHARM', u'AMARAJABAT', u'EICHERMOT', u'QUESS', u'SBILIFE', u'HCLTECH', u'SHREECEM', u'UPL', u'ESCORTS', u'DLF', u'BRITANNIA', u'MPHASIS', u'LUPIN', u'ONGC', u'GSPL', u'TATAGLOBAL', u'DISHTV', u'NIACL', u'NMDC', u'VARROC', u'SUNTV', u'IGL', u'GLENMARK', u'WIPRO', u'MARICO', u'COROMANDEL', u'TORNTPHARM', u'ASHOKLEY', u'MRPL', u'OBEROIRLTY', u'BIOCON', u'HINDALCO', u'SAIL', u'MGL', u'ICICIBANK', u'NTPC', u'BAJFINANCE', u'ACC', u'CONCOR', u'IDEA', u'RBLBANK', u'PEL', u'MUTHOOTFIN', u'M&MFIN', u'JUBILANT', u'OFSS', u'EDELWEISS', u'HEXAWARE', u'BEL', u'ADANIPORTS', u'DRREDDY', u'CROMPTON', u'ASIANPAINT', u'JSWSTEEL', u'AJANTPHARM', u'AXISBANK', u'SPARC', u'APOLLOHOSP', u'RECLTD', u'GODREJAGRO', u'JSWENERGY', u'ADANIPOWER', u'SRF', u'BANKBARODA', u'IDBI', u'HEG', u'ENGINERSIN', u'TATAMTRDVR', u'LTI', u'IBVENTURES', u'NHPC', u'BATAINDIA', u'HEROMOTOCO', u'ZEEL', u'AUROPHARMA', u'HDFCBANK', u'NAUKRI', u'ULTRACEMCO', u'ITC', u'HUDCO', u'TORNTPOWER', u'INFY', u'MINDTREE', u'IBULHSGFIN', u'BHARTIARTL', u'TATASTEEL', u'GODREJIND', u'AMBUJACEM', u'M&M', u'POWERGRID', u'HDFCLIFE', u'MANAPPURAM', u'DHFL', u'RPOWER', u'BALKRISIND', u'ABFRL', u'PNBHOUSING', u'HINDZINC', u'STRTECH', u'RAJESHEXPO', u'TATAMOTORS', u'TATAPOWER', u'DMART', u'CIPLA', u'HAVELLS', u'COALINDIA', u'LICHSGFIN', u'JUBLFOOD', u'BAJAJ-AUTO', u'DABUR', u'CUMMINSIND', u'NATIONALUM', u'INFRATEL', u'ABB', u'VEDL', u'BHEL', u'UBL', u'BOSCHLTD', u'BAJAJFINSV', u'TECHM', u'INDIANB', u'CASTROLIND', u'PIIND', u'PFC', u'PNB', u'BANDHANBNK', u'YESBANK', u'ALKEM', u'INDUSINDBK', u'SIEMENS', u'TVSMOTOR', u'GSKCONS', u'SRTRANSFIN', u'ICICIPRULI', u'VGUARD'])
```

to be of form

```
convertedset =   ([[u'DIVISLAB', u'TITAN', u'JINDALSTEL', u'ENDURANCE', u'PGHH'], [u'GMRINFRA', u'UNIONBANK', u'RAMCOCEM', u'GAIL', u'ICICIGI'],[u'L&TFH', u'HINDUNILVR', u'SBIN'...]])
```

Comment: Is there any criteria for how the elements should be grouped? Or just any 5 elements in each new set?

Comment: just 5 elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
symbol_list = [u'DIVISLAB', u'TITAN', u'JINDALSTEL', u'ENDURANCE', u'PGHH', u'GMRINFRA', u'UNIONBANK', u'RAMCOCEM', u'GAIL', u'ICICIGI', u'L&TFH', u'HINDUNILVR', u'SBIN', u'PRESTIGE', u'BERGEPAINT', u'LT', u'HINDPETRO', u'RELIANCE', u'GODREJCP', u'GRAPHITE', u'RELINFRA', u'NBCC', u'MCDOWELL-N', u'SYNGENE', u'IOC', u'PETRONET', u'SUNPHARMA', u'GRASIM', u'FEDERALBNK', u'GRUH', u'CANBK', u'BBTC', u'FCONSUMER', u'MFSL', u'MRF', u'TATACHEM', u'IDFCFIRSTB', u'FRETAIL', u'OIL', u'DBL', u'PFIZER', u'BANKINDIA', u'CHOLAFIN', u'MARUTI', u'HDFC', u'EXIDEIND', u'VOLTAS', u'PAGEIND', u'RELCAPITAL', u'HDFCAMC', u'INDHOTEL', u'INDIGO', u'BHARATFORG', u'BPCL', u'MOTHERSUMI', u'COLPAL', u'LTTS', u'BAJAJHLDNG', u'GICRE', u'KOTAKBANK', u'ABCAPITAL', u'CADILAHC', u'PIDILITIND', u'APOLLOTYRE', u'AUBANK', u'TCS', u'NATCOPHARM', u'AMARAJABAT', u'EICHERMOT', u'QUESS', u'SBILIFE', u'HCLTECH', u'SHREECEM', u'UPL', u'ESCORTS', u'DLF', u'BRITANNIA', u'MPHASIS', u'LUPIN', u'ONGC', u'GSPL', u'TATAGLOBAL', u'DISHTV', u'NIACL', u'NMDC', u'VARROC', u'SUNTV', u'IGL', u'GLENMARK', u'WIPRO', u'MARICO', u'COROMANDEL', u'TORNTPHARM', u'ASHOKLEY', u'MRPL', u'OBEROIRLTY', u'BIOCON', u'HINDALCO', u'SAIL', u'MGL', u'ICICIBANK', u'NTPC', u'BAJFINANCE', u'ACC', u'CONCOR', u'IDEA', u'RBLBANK', u'PEL', u'MUTHOOTFIN', u'M&MFIN', u'JUBILANT', u'OFSS', u'EDELWEISS', u'HEXAWARE', u'BEL', u'ADANIPORTS', u'DRREDDY', u'CROMPTON', u'ASIANPAINT', u'JSWSTEEL', u'AJANTPHARM', u'AXISBANK', u'SPARC', u'APOLLOHOSP', u'RECLTD', u'GODREJAGRO', u'JSWENERGY', u'ADANIPOWER', u'SRF', u'BANKBARODA', u'IDBI', u'HEG', u'ENGINERSIN', u'TATAMTRDVR', u'LTI', u'IBVENTURES', u'NHPC', u'BATAINDIA', u'HEROMOTOCO', u'ZEEL', u'AUROPHARMA', u'HDFCBANK', u'NAUKRI', u'ULTRACEMCO', u'ITC', u'HUDCO', u'TORNTPOWER', u'INFY', u'MINDTREE', u'IBULHSGFIN', u'BHARTIARTL', u'TATASTEEL', u'GODREJIND', u'AMBUJACEM', u'M&M', u'POWERGRID', u'HDFCLIFE', u'MANAPPURAM', u'DHFL', u'RPOWER', u'BALKRISIND', u'ABFRL', u'PNBHOUSING', u'HINDZINC', u'STRTECH', u'RAJESHEXPO', u'TATAMOTORS', u'TATAPOWER', u'DMART', u'CIPLA', u'HAVELLS', u'COALINDIA', u'LICHSGFIN', u'JUBLFOOD', u'BAJAJ-AUTO', u'DABUR', u'CUMMINSIND', u'NATIONALUM', u'INFRATEL', u'ABB', u'VEDL', u'BHEL', u'UBL', u'BOSCHLTD', u'BAJAJFINSV', u'TECHM', u'INDIANB', u'CASTROLIND', u'PIIND', u'PFC', u'PNB', u'BANDHANBNK', u'YESBANK', u'ALKEM', u'INDUSINDBK', u'SIEMENS', u'TVSMOTOR', u'GSKCONS', u'SRTRANSFIN', u'ICICIPRULI', u'VGUARD']

convertedlist = [symbol_list[i:i+5] for i in range(0, len(symbol_list), 5)]
```

**Output** :

```
[['DIVISLAB', 'TITAN', 'JINDALSTEL', 'ENDURANCE', 'PGHH'], 
 ['GMRINFRA', 'UNIONBANK', 'RAMCOCEM', 'GAIL', 'ICICIGI'], 
 ['L&TFH', 'HINDUNILVR', 'SBIN', 'PRESTIGE', 'BERGEPAINT'], 
 ['LT', 'HINDPETRO', 'RELIANCE', 'GODREJCP', 'GRAPHITE'], ...]
```

Note :

1. Don't convert `symbol_list` to a set as even if not converted to a set it would contain unique elements 'cause `len(symbol_list) == len(set(symbol_list))`. Both are having 201 elements.

Comment: 'set' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: symbollist is a set

Comment: @LokeshAgrawal Don't convert it into a set in first hand, cause there is no duplicate element inside it.

Comment: Or convert the set to a list, then use this method.

Answer (score 1):

This can be handled by the below code, without using any lib,

```
split_size = 5
converted_list = []
# ouput list
split_list = []
# chlid list items, part of the output list

for index, elt in enumerate(symbol_list):    
    split_list.append(elt)
    # we append to the list till the split_size cut
    # and then append this list to the output list and continue
    if index and index % split_size == 0:
       converted_list.append(split_list)
       split_list = []
```

Comment: But the question says, " I want to convert this set to a list of list"